# &a[x] in C what is type of value is returned

Tags: c++, c, operators, memory-address

The following expression is used in C to get the address of a particular element.

```
 &a[x]
```

What is the type of the value returned? What is this dependent on? Is it always the same by convenetion or is it dependent on the operating system?

---

I need to know this because:

I need to extract a bit pattern from within this pointer so Im trying to understand whether the value is hex or binary. When you say a pointer is it like: 0x25434 or like 0111000111?

Becuase that would affect how I extract my bits

Comment: It's a pointer to a[x]....

Comment: binary and hex are just two different ways to represent a number. Neither refer to a datatype.

Comment: you've added the C++ tag, whilst your question seems to be focused on C. Which is it?

Comment: Correct me if Im wrong, I thought anything with C also applies to C++? hence the tagging

Comment: @banditKing C and C++ are two languages that happen to share a usuable common subset, but C++ is not a superset of C and there are many incompatibilities, even in low-level semantics.

Comment: @StephenLin: The answer to this particular question happens to be the same in C and C++, at least in the absence of operator overloading. (Hmm, can `&` be overloaded in C++?)

Comment: @KeithThompson yes, it can :D anyway OP should understand the distinction anyway, regardless of if it matters in a particular case or not (since that isn't known *a priori*)

Comment: *Why* do you need to extract the bit pattern from a pointer? That's rarely a useful thing to do. Pointers are best thought of as, well, as pointers, opaque values on which you can perform certain operations such as pointer arithmetic and dereferencing. In particular, pointers are *not* numbers (though they may have a similar internal representation). Suggested reading: section 4 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For an array of T, the type of the returned value is pointer-to-T, declared as `T *`:

```
T a[] = ...;
T *ptr = &a[n];
```

How this pointer is displayed—in binary, hex, decimal, Morse—is entirely up to the code displaying it. The `%p` format value is a popular choice for debugging, and it will typically print the pointer's value (the memory address) in hexadecimal.

If the address the pointer points to needs to be expressed as a number, it can be obtained by casting the pointer to the `uintptr_t` integral type:

```
uintptr_t addr = (uintptr_t) ptr;
```

The bits of the address can then be inspected with the usual arithmetic and binary operators.

Comment: I need to extract a bit pattern from within this pointer so Im trying to understand whether the value is hex or binary. When you say a pointer is it like: 0x25434 or like 0111000111?

Becuase that would affect how I extract my bits

Comment: You wrote two different *representations* of a number. First, a number doesn't have a representation, you only use a representation when *writing* them. Second, pointers are not numbers, you can convert them to such (to print them) but pointers behave different. Calculating with pointers is called pointer arithmetic and it behaves different than number arithmetic.

Comment: @banditKing This is not how numbers work in C. Unlike in scripting languages, a C number is always a number, you cannot observe its digits other than by calculating them from the number using arithmetics. Because of that, bases come into play only when reading or writing out the number.

Comment: Pointers might not even be represented as numbers internally...one example (a Lisp machine) is described [here](http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html)

Comment: @StephenLin A conforming C implementation must still be able to convert a pointer to `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t` and convert that number back into the original pointer. Of course, the implementation is free to devise completely arbitrary mapping between the pointers and those numbers that has nothing to do with hardware addresses. For example, it could store the pointer objects in a table with the "addresses" being indices into the table.

Comment: @user4815162342 oh yes, I know, I wasn't disagreeing, just clarifying...sorry if it was unclear

Comment: @user4815162342: A C implementation is not required to have an integer type capable of representing pointer values without loss of information. For example, pointers might be 128 bits, and the largest supported integer type might be 64 bits. In that case, the types `uintptr_t` and `intptr_t` won't even exist. (And pre-C99 implementations don't necessarily have them either.)

Comment: @KeithThompson just to clarify for my edification, is the round-trip conversion guaranteed to yield back the original pointer if the types **do** exist or can a DS9K implemention provide anyway them without that guarantee?

Comment: @KeithThompson Good point, I forgot that these types are optional in C99.

Comment: @StephenLin Round-trip is guaranteed, see C99 §7.18.1.4. (NB I had to look up DS9K!)

Comment: @user4815162342: On the other hand, I've never heard of a real-world (C99 or later) implementation that doesn't have `uintptr_t` and `intptr_t`. You can check whether they exist with `#ifdef UINTPTR_MAX` and `#ifdef INTPTR_MAX` (possibly preceded by `#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L`).

Answer (score 0):

if a[] is array of int, it will be int*, for example.
If you new to C language, i would recommend you read this book http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language